# JavaFX, обновление свойства textProperty

Tags: javafx

Создаю динамически несколько компонентов:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    Switch sw = new Switch();
    StringProperty str = new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(shop.bag[i].get()));
    Text text1 = new Text();
    text1.textProperty().bind(str);
    final int finalI = i;
    sw.action = () - > {
        ind[0] = finalI * 3 + sw.index;
        str[ind[0]].set(String.valueOf(shop.bag[finalI * 3 + sw.index].get()));
    };
}
```

Код выше работает нормально, но первоначально текст не обновляется, обновление происходит только после вызова метода `sw.setOnMouseClicked()`. Если же `StringProperty str` вынести из цикла и сделать как поле, то у всех компонентов текст будет одинаков. 
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Вы попробуйте код

```
ind[0] = finalI * 3 + sw.index;
str[ind[0]].set(String.valueOf(shop.bag[finalI * 3 + sw.index].get()));
```

поместить вне `sw.action`.
Либо проверьте, что у Вас в `shop.bag[i].get()` на момент инициализации.

У Вас присвоения значения при инициализации не происходит.

**Обновление**

Сохраняйте элементы, созданные динамически в ArrayList и потом для каждого элемента производите инициализацию значений их свойств, после того, как подгрузите данные в shop.bag. Так у Вас ещё и индекс опорный появится.

Comment: Получается что при инициализации компонентов shop.bag еще пустой, не знаю как его обновить. Если связать непосредственно, то текст одинаков у всех компонентов

Comment: text1.textProperty().bind(shop.bag[finalI * 3 + sw.index].asString());

Comment: У компонентов типа Switch которые создаются в цикле, при клике меняется индекс (свойство index), и когда свойство StringProperty str внутри этого цикла, то все работает. Когда выношу str из цикла, делаю его массивом свойств, то нет реакции на изменения индекса.